# Image Data,iphone

Tags: iphone

i am converting image data to bytes by using below code..

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(m_imageView.image,90);
unsigned char *bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[imageData bytes];
```

same image is coverting to bytes by using .net, in that they are using some encoding techs...

iphonesdk and .net bytes are not in sync...

do i need to use encoding techs for that bytes....if so please please provide me the solution with code :)

Thanks in advance....

Comment: bytes returns a **const** pointer: `- (const void *)bytes`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for raw color data (rgba array), or saving to a file?

The JPEG encoding is not unique for a given quality level, so you're not going to have the exact same data in .net vs Cocoa.

Comment: thanks for your replay.....i hv one more problem.....in above code from bytesPtr i am getting bytes and am able to print all the bytes usin code:  for (int i = 0; i < [imageData length]; i++) {
  NSLog(@"%d",bytePtr[i]);                                 
 }



now my problem is i want to send all these bytes to web services...how can i do this...



thanks in advance...